It is possible to store data on the Android Webview Window Object at start with Capacitor/Ionic?
I have some configuration variables that depend on which flavor the Android App is using, including some auth variables that are needed for the angular app start up.
I need to write some of that data into a global const in the window object but I do not find any way to do it.
I have tried creating a Capacitor Plugin and calling
override fun load() {
    this.bridge.webView.evaluateJavascript("const __myTest = 'hello world'", null);
}

or with
override fun handleOnStart() {
  super.handleOnStart()
  this.bridge.webView.evaluateJavascript("const __myTest = 'hello world'", null);
}

But even when that part is called, it does not set anything (probably the webview is not defined at that time)
Is this even possible? I do not want to define a plugin call because I would need to change all the initialization of the app and I am trying to prevent that.

For creating a global object/variable you have to put it on window object, or use var instead of const.
Then, you can use this.bridge.eval("window.__myTest = 'hello world';", null);, which runs evaluateJavascript under the hood but on main thread.

There are a few ways I can think of without involving the native side of things, and maybe one works in your project.

If you're using Vite, import.meta.env.VITE_* allows environment variables to be passed to the build, and referenced directly in your Vue project code. Vite can also read them from a .env file, which a build script can generate if you need a more dynamic configuration. The VITE_ prefix on the variable is required, AFAIK.
https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode
const config = {
  foo: import.meta.env.VITE_FOO,
  bar: import.meta.env.VITE_BAR,
}


You can sed something in index.html:
<script>let config = {};</script>

#!/usr/bin/env bash

FOO_VALUE=bar
BAZ_VALUE=2006

CONFIG=$(cat <<END
{
  "foo": "${FOO_VALUE}",
  "baz": ${BAZ_VALUE}
}
END
)

CONFIG=$(echo $CONFIG | tr -d "\n")

sed -i '' -e "s|let config = {};|const config = ${CONFIG};|g" dist/index.html


Another approach could be to create config.js during the build, and load it from index.html:
<script src="config.js"></script>




All the data needed already exists on the native side, for it to be written on javascript again will require maintenance of both parts :/
